# In php how to make a array?

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$str="Diwas"
```

I want to make an array of every two alphabet so I used

```
str_split($str,2);
```

So my array will be now

```
Di
wa
s
```

But I want to make an array in such a way that the result will be.

```
Di
iw
wa
as
s
```

Comment: Perhaps something like: `$str='Diwas';

$result = array_merge(
    str_split($str, 2),
    str_split(substr($str, 1), 2)
);
var_dump($result);`

Comment: works but instead of Di iw wa s it becomes Di wa s iw as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is more ressource friendly than a preg_*

```
$str="Diwas"

$myArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i)
    $myArray[] = substr($str, $i, 2);
```

Comment: @Lifestohack you're welcome. Don't forget to mark this topic as solved ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use preg_match_all:

```
$str="Diwas";
preg_match_all('/(?=(\w\w?))/',$str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Yields:

```
Array ( [0] => Di [1] => iw [2] => wa [3] => as [4] => s )
```